# How to do LEFT OUTER JOIN in Laravel raw expression

Tags: laravel

This raw query is working well with two commented lines.

```php
$q = DB::table('stock_items')
          ->selectRaw('stock_parts.title')
          ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) as qtyAvailable')
          ->selectRaw('SUM(shipments.item_cost) as totalValue')
          //->selectRaw('stock_alerts.minimum AS minimum')
          ->join('stock_parts', 'stock_items.stock_part_id', '=', 'stock_parts.id')
          ->join('shipments', 'shipments.id', '=', 'stock_items.shipment_id')
          //->leftJoin('stock_alerts', 'stock_alerts.stock_part_id', '=', 'stock_items.stock_part_id')
          ->whereNull('stock_items.status')
          ->where('stock_items.current_stock_id', '=', $stockId)
          ->groupBy('stock_parts.id')
          ->get();
```

The commented lines are needed to get information from another table.

In raw SQL I was using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and it works.

Uncommenting those lines it shows this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause
and contains nonaggregated column 'rdphone-dev.stock_alerts.minimum'
which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;
this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select stock_parts.title, COUNT(*) as qtyAvailable, SUM(shipments.item_cost) as totalValue, stock_alerts.minimum AS minimum from `stock_items` inner join `stock_parts` on `stock_items`.`stock_part_id` = `stock_parts`.`id` inner join `shipments` on `shipments`.`id` = `stock_items`.`shipment_id` left join `stock_alerts` on `stock_alerts`.`stock_part_id` = `stock_items`.`stock_part_id` where `stock_items`.`status` is null and `stock_items`.`current_stock_id` = 1 group by `stock_parts`.`id`)",
```

What is the correct way to do LEFT OUTER JOIN in Laravel 5.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every field used in the select has to be included in the group by, I added the minimum column in the `groupBy`.

```
$q = DB::table('stock_items')
          ->selectRaw('stock_parts.title')
          ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) as qtyAvailable')
          ->selectRaw('SUM(shipments.item_cost) as totalValue')
          ->selectRaw('stock_alerts.minimum AS minimum')
          ->join('stock_parts', 'stock_items.stock_part_id', '=', 'stock_parts.id')
          ->join('shipments', 'shipments.id', '=', 'stock_items.shipment_id')
          ->leftJoin('stock_alerts', 'stock_alerts.stock_part_id', '=', 'stock_items.stock_part_id')
          ->whereNull('stock_items.status')
          ->where('stock_items.current_stock_id', '=', $stockId)
          ->groupBy('stock_parts.id', 'minimum')
          ->get();
```